# Integer Y with N Repeating Digits of X?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

I have a single Base 10 digit `X`. I want to return number `Y` where `Y` is digit `X` repeated `N` times.

For example:

```
X = 2
N = 4
Y = 2222

X = 9
N = 7
Y = 9999999

X = 1
N = 1
Y = 1
```

Is there a simple mathematical method whereby I can return this `Y` given `X` and `N`? Thanks!

Note: If tags are bad, please suggest--I don't know enough about math to even properly frame and categorize the question.

Comment: How about $Y = X*\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}10^{k-1}$

Comment: Not sure what you want.  $\frac {10^n-1}{9}$ is a string of $n$ $1's$, so multiplying this by $x$ appears to get the job done....but presumably you want something else?

Comment: @lulu this seems to work perfectly for `1`, but how would I do the same for `2` or `3`?

Comment: @ganeshie8 I'm embarrassed to say that I don't know how  `∑` is used :)

Comment: Just multiply...$2\times \frac {10^3-1}{9}=222$, for example.  Hard to believe this is the best programming solution though.

Comment: @lulu got it! Thanks! Sorry, multiplying by `X` seems obvious now. If you post this as an answer I'll accept. Bonus points if you can explain how it's working in simple terms :) Nah, not anything I want to use practically in programming--just wanted to understand how something easy to do with strings could be done with math!

Comment: As a variant, you could also take $\lfloor 10^n\times \frac x9\rfloor $, where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ denote "greatest integer not exceeding $x$".  But I think someone else will provide a better solution from a programming point of view.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I'm just having trouble understanding how ganshie8's answer translates to code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to get a simple mathematical representation for the number in question:

The key observation is that $$10^n-1=\overbrace{9\dots 9}^{n\,times} $$

It follows that 
$$\frac {10^n-1}9=\overbrace{1\dots 1}^{n\,times} $$

And hence that 
$$x \times \frac {10^n-1}9=\overbrace{x\dots x}^{n\,times} $$

For $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

As remarked in the comments, this is impractical from a coding point of view (as exponentiation to large powers is a very costly operation).